# No overload matches this call. Overload 1 of 2, '(props: ViewProps | Readonly<ViewProps>): View', gave the following error. (React Native)

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

```
(alias) class View
import View
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: ViewProps | Readonly<ViewProps>): View', gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: Element[]; style: { flexDirection: "row"; alignItems: "center"; marginTop: number; }; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<View> & Readonly<ViewProps>'.
      Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<View> & Readonly<ViewProps>'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: ViewProps, context: any): View', gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: Element[]; style: { flexDirection: "row"; alignItems: "center"; marginTop: number; }; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<View> & Readonly<ViewProps>'.
      Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<View> & Readonly<ViewProps>'.ts(2769)
```

I have no idea why i'm getting this error.
Even reviewed other stack overflow similar questions. problem not resolved.

I'm using stylesheet which is imported from react native.

Code:-

```
       <View style={styles.createPostContainer}>
        <View style={styles.addPostButtonContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            data-elementId="button_next"
            onPress={this.discordChanges}
          >
            <Image
              data-elementId="image_Back"
              style={[DS ? styles.image_BackImage_5inch : styles.image_BackImage]}
              source={back}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <Text
          data-elementId="textlabel_Payments"
          style={[DS ? styles.textlabel_PaymentsText_5inch : styles.textlabel_PaymentsText]}
        >
          Create Post
        </Text>
      </View>
```

My project info:-

```
npx react-native info
info Fetching system and libraries information...
System:
    OS: macOS 13.0.1
    CPU: (8) arm64 Apple M1
    Memory: 199.59 MB / 16.00 GB
    Shell: 5.8.1 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 18.9.1 - /opt/homebrew/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.18 - /opt/homebrew/bin/yarn
    npm: 8.19.1 - /opt/homebrew/bin/npm
    Watchman: 2022.09.19.00 - /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: DriverKit 21.4, iOS 16.0, macOS 12.3, tvOS 16.0, watchOS 9.0
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 2021.3 AI-213.7172.25.2113.9014738
    Xcode: 14.0/14A309 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: ^9.1.1 => 9.1.3 
    react-native: file:./packages/blocks/core/node_modules/react-native => 0.61.3 
  npmGlobalPackages:
    react-native: 0.70.1
```

I tried decreasing typescript version. not sure why i did it, just tried it.
Hoping anyone can help me with this. :)

Comment: The "project info" you have here isn't useful.  Publish the failing code and its related type instead.

Comment: added the code that failing, actually i have big project, and the whole project has bunch of files, all of them are having the same TS2769
Also Having same issue for Text Component.

Comment: @VishnuVardhan have you found solution?

Comment: No I have not found correct solution.
But for now i am using // @ts-nocheck to ignore the type error to continue working.

Comment: @arkan4ik92 yes I have found the solution now. Check the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added This Code in `yarn.lock` file and then deleted all node modules and reinstalled all dependencies.

> "@types/react@*": version "17.0.38" resolved
> "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@types/react/-/react-17.0.38.tgz#f24249fefd89357d5fa71f739a686b8d7c7202bd"
> integrity
> sha512-SI92X1IA+FMnP3qM5m4QReluXzhcmovhZnLNm3pyeQlooi02qI7sLiepEYqT678uNiyc25XfCqxREFpy3W7YhQ==
> dependencies: "@types/prop-types" "*" "@types/scheduler" "*" csstype
> "^3.0.2"

This solution was referred to me by my colleague. Also make sure to remove existing `@types/react@` then replace with it my solution above. Please let me know guys if the solution works or not for you. Thank you for all of your help.

Comment: After Changing above solution, if not works, try to install **@types/react-native@latest**

Answer (score 1):

Adding the "resolutions" field to your **package.json** file allows you to specify specific versions for conflicting or incompatible packages. By doing this, you can ensure that the correct versions of @types/react and @types/react-dom are used in your project, which may resolve the type conflicts you are experiencing.

Here's how you can add the "resolutions" field to your package.json:

```
"resolutions": {
  "@types/react": "^17.0.38",
  "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.11"
}
```